# Oracle SQL LISTAGG function - include multiple values

Tags: oracle, listagg

Hi would it be possible to include a count against each value in LISTAGG?

eg.
current result using

```
SELECT 
CLIENT, 
AIRLINE, 
COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) AS DISTINCT_CUSTOMER, 
COUNT(ORDER_ID) AS NO_ORDERS, 
LISTAGG(DISTINCT(FLIGHT), ', ') 
   WITHIN GROUP BY (ORDER BY FLIGHT) AS FLIGHT
GROUP BY CLIENT, AIRLINE


CLIENT        AIRLINE      DISTINCT_customers    NO_ORDERS   FLIGHT
ABC           Qantas       18038                 26000       QF123, QF456, QF789
```

Expected results

```
CLIENT        AIRLINE      DISTINCT_customers    NO_ORDERS   FLIGHT
ABC           Qantas       18038                 26000       QF123 (3), QF456 (10), QF789 (10)
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data; a complete example of your code (you have omitted the `FROM` clause); and the expected output for that sample data. I would guess that you have the data in multiple tables and are using `JOIN`s in the `FROM` clause that you have omitted and it is possible that you will get a better solution if you give details of the tables because the aggregation could be done before joining (rather than after) which may make it much simpler; but we can't suggest that without table details.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use two steps: one that fetches data *without* `listagg`, which is then applied to that result in the final step.

For example (based on Scott's `emp` table):

```
SQL> select deptno, job, count(*) cnt
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO JOB              CNT
---------- --------- ----------
        20 CLERK              2
        30 SALESMAN           4
        20 MANAGER            1
        30 CLERK              1
        10 PRESIDENT          1
        30 MANAGER            1
        10 CLERK              1
        10 MANAGER            1
        20 ANALYST            2

9 rows selected.
```

Previous query is used as a CTE (named `temp`), and `listagg` contains `job` along with number of employees (that's what `count` returns) who do that job:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select deptno, job, count(*) cnt
  3     from emp
  4     group by deptno, job
  5    )
  6  select deptno,
  7    listagg(job ||' ('|| cnt ||')', ', ') within group (order by job) result
  8  from temp
  9  group by deptno;

    DEPTNO RESULT
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLERK (1), MANAGER (1), PRESIDENT (1)
        20 ANALYST (2), CLERK (2), MANAGER (1)
        30 CLERK (1), MANAGER (1), SALESMAN (4)

SQL>
```

---

Applied to your query (kind of invalid; misses the `from` clause), that would be something like this:

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (  SELECT client,
                airline,
                COUNT (DISTINCT customer_id) AS distinct_customer,
                COUNT (order_id) AS no_orders,
                flight
           FROM your_table
       GROUP BY client, airline, flight)
  SELECT client,
         airline,
         distinct_customer,
         LISTAGG (flight || ' (' || no_orders || ')', ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL) AS flight
    FROM temp
GROUP BY client, airline, distinct_customer;
```

Comment: The final query is incorrect as you do not want to include `distinct_customer` in the group by clause as each flight is likely to have a different number of customers and, as a result, you are not going to be aggregating the flights.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to get counts per client, airline and flight and also distinct customers per client and airline, you need two separate aggregations that you then join.

Here is a query doing this stepby step:

```
with per_flight as
(
  select client, airline, flight, count(*) as no_orders
  from orders
  group by client, airline, flight
)
, per_airline1 as
(
  select
    client, airline,
    listagg(flight || '(' || no_orders || ')', ', ') 
       within group by (order by flight) as flights
  from per_flight
  group by client, airline
)
, per_airline2 as
(
  select
    client, airline,
    count(distinct customer_id) as distinct_customer,
    count(*) as no_orders
  from orders
  group by client, airline
)
select
  client, airline,
  per_airline2.distinct_customer,
  per_airline2.no_orders,
  per_airline1.flights
from per_airline1
join per_airline2 using (client, airline);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate for each flight and then aggregate again:

```sql
SELECT client,
       airline,
       ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)
         FROM   table_name c
         WHERE  t.client = c.client
         AND    t.airline = c.airline ) AS distinct_customer,
       SUM(no_orders) AS no_orders,
       LISTAGG(flight || ' (' || no_flights || ')', ',')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY flight) AS flight
FROM   (
  SELECT client,
         airline,
         flight,
         COUNT(order_id) AS no_orders,
         COUNT(something) AS no_flights -- you do not provide sample data so we do not know
                                        -- what we should count here.
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY
         client,
         airline,
         flight
) t
GROUP BY
       client,
       airline
```

*Note: Finding the count of the `DISTINCT` customers in the inner-most query and then `SUM`ming it in the outer query would be incorrect as you could get the same customer taking different flights with the same client and airline and then when you total it in the outer query you would be double counting that customer. Instead you need to use either a correlated sub-query or a join to another sub-query where you find the distinct customers.*